# AutoFill of user's email addr fails for Internet Explorer but works for FireFox and Safari

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer

Autofill fails for IE, but works for Safari and FireFox.

Users for my VisualBasic2010 web site must enter their email address twice to log in.
But when they come back to the web, IE never automatically fills it in.

HERE'S WHAT IS ON THE PAGE........

Enter your email address: 
[textbox]

Enter your email address again:
[textbox]

AND HERE'S THE HTML..........................

```
<input name="USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS1" type="text" id="USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS1" title="Your email address for your Prayer Shepherd account." style="width:385px;"/>
<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span id="LOGIN_STATUS_MESSAGE1" style="background-color:#FFFF80;"></span>
<br/>
<span id="EMAIL_AGAIN_LABEL" title="Entering your email address again confirms that it is correct.">Enter your email address again:<br>
</span>
<input name="USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_AGAIN" type="text" id="USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_AGAIN" title="Your email address again, to verify that it is correct." style="width:385px;"/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="LOGIN_BUTTON" value="Login..." id="LOGIN_BUTTON" title="Logs in and shows all commands." style="font-size:X-Small;"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of IE do you have? This website has a solution for this problem for IE8:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/ie8-auto-complete-not-working/28e05990-d80e-4edc-9271-299f1c61555e

Have you tried this on another pc? Also try resetting the browser settings via tools>options, also some add ons or toolbars might stop autofill e.g. Google toolbar.